# In what order are Lisp files evaluated in this scenario?

Tags: init-file, prelude, load

Suppose I structure my Emacs (prelude) customizations like this guy:

https://github.com/NicholasKirchner/prelude/tree/master/personal

What is the load order of these files (for example)?

```
gnus-init.el
layouts.el
start.el
```

The load order is sometimes important, because often I'm trying
to invoke a function that hasn't been defined yet.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs will load your `init.el` file first. Nothing else gets loaded unless `init.el` says so. You can answer your question by working through `init.el` and looking for `require` or `load` lines, which will be processed in the order they appear. This is recursive, so if `init.el` requires `sourceA.el`, and `sourceA.el` requires `sourceB.el`, then `sourceB.el` gets loaded too.